# Do inherited getter methods need to be overridden?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm wondering if you make a subclass with fields of the same name as the parent class, do getter methods invoked on the subclass object access it's fields or the parent's fields? Or do the methods need to be written again and overridden?

Comment: You can actually write it as a code (whatever you asked ) and can check by yourself right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions need to be written again and overridden. See this example:

```
static class A {
    private int i = 0;

    public A() {
    }

    public A(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    private int i;

    public B(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B(5);

    System.out.println(b.getI());
}
```

Output: `0` because it is using `A.getI()`, which is referring to the `i` field in `A`.

Now the same code but using `B.getI()`:

```
static class A {
    private int i = 0;

    public A() {
    }

    public A(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    private int i;

    public B(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getI() {
        return this.i;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B(5);

    System.out.println(b.getI());
}
```

Output: `5`.